# How to display two query in one table, query before and after? [PHP and MYSQL]

Tags: php, mysql

The desired result is a table that has the following columns: item name, category, number of items, a condition of the previous seven or fewer items, the number of excellent items, the number of good items, the number of broken items and the condition of the latest items.

**The desired table result:**
[image]

**Code:**

```html
<table style="font-size: 0.9em" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4"><center>Item Data</center></th>
    <th colspan="4"><center>the Prev. Cond. of the Item</center></th>
    <th colspan="4"><center>the Latest Cond. of the Item</center></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><center>No </center></th>
    <th><center>Item Name </center></th>
    <th><center>Item Category</center></th>
    <th><center>Number of Items </center></th>
    <th><center>Date</center></th>
    <th><center>Excellent</center></th>
    <th><center>Good</center></th>
    <th><center>Broken</center></th>
    <th><center>Date</center></th>
    <th><center>Excellent</center></th>
    <th><center>Good</center></th>
    <th><center>Broken</center></th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
  $conn= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sirama");
  $rest = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM `inventory`
  INNER JOIN `status_item`
  ON `inventory`.`idItem` = `status_item`.`code_item`
  WHERE `inventory`.`address`='$_GET[room]'");  
  $i = 1; //for number
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rest)):
?>
  <tr>
    <td><center><?php echo $i++ ?> </center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $row['item_name'];?> </center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $row['item_category'];?> </center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $row['number'];?> </center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $row['date'];?> </center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $row['excellent_total'];?> </center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $row['good_total'];?> </center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $row['broken_total'];?> </center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $row['date'];?> </center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $row['excellent_total'];?> </center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $row['good_total'];?> </center></td>
    <td><center><?php echo $row['broken_total'];?> </center></td>
  </tr>  
<?php endwhile; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The database structure be like

**inventory table**

```
idItem (PK)
item_name
item_category
number
address (FK)
```

**status_item table**

```
idStatus (PK)
code_item (FK)
date
excellent_total
good_total
broken_total
```

I don't know query to display status item join with inventory to prev and latest status column in the above table from status_item table database. Where prev cond column is if data is less than or equal 7 days ago, the latest cond column is the latest data,

Comment: Please share your data table details, if possible create a fiddle.

Comment: hi thank you, this is the updated fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e37e73

Comment: Please minimize your fiddle. We do not need everything. Make it minimal

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7533b2/2

Comment: So you basically want the latest two rows from the `status_item` table for each row in the `inventory` table?

Comment: How to display status item join with inventory to prev and latest status column in the above table from status_item table database. Where prev cond column is if data is less than or equal 7 days ago, the latest cond column is the latest data,